# Given $a+b=8$, $ax+by=9$, $ax^2+by^2=33$, $ax^3+by^3=60$, find $ax^4+by^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

> Given $$\begin{align}a+b&=8\\ax+by&=9\\ax^2+by^2&=33\\ax^3+by^3&=60\end{align}$$
> Find $ax^4+by^4$

I really have no idea here.

Without coefficients $a$ and $b$, we can simply figure out $xy$ and find what we want by linear recurrences, but that doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: "*find what we want by linear recurrences*" $\;-\;$ Indeed, let $\,x+y=s\,$, $\,xy=p\,$ and $\,z_n=ax^n+by^n\,$, then $\,z_{n+1}=sz_n-pz_{n-1}\,$. Solve the last two equalities for $\,s, p\,$, then you can calculate the next term.

Comment: Does the recurrence still hold if we have coefficients for the variables?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha finds no integer solutions but it does offer [these two](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+a%2Bb%3D8%2C+ax%2Bby%3D9%2C+ax%5E2%2Bby%5E2%3D33%2C+ax%5E3%2Bby%5E3%3D60).

Comment: There have been several questions like this asked and answered on this site previously. Suggest you search for them.

Comment: Reminded me of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4310469/finding-cotab-if-tan3a2-tan3b-6-tan4a2-tan4b-18-tan5a2

Comment: @Cyh1368 $x, y$ are the roots of $z^2 - s z + p = 0$ so $x^2=sx-p$ and $y^2=sy-p$. Multiply the equalities by $ax^n$ and $by^n$ respectively then add them up to get the recurrence.

Comment: @poetasis Right, the "trick" here is to get $ax^4+by^4$ without calculating $a,b,x,y$ first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the hint in comments, letting $x+y=s$ and $xy=p$
we can write the following linear system:
$$60=33s-9p\\33=9s-8p$$
Solving gives $s=1,p=-3$ and
$$ax^4+by^4=60s-33p=159$$